# What are Binary Graphs?

Tags: graph, tinkerpop

I came across this term while going through Apache TinkerPop [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graph-computing)

> When modeling a graph in a computer and applying it to modern data sets and practices, the generic mathematically-oriented, binary graph is extended to support both labels and key/value properties

Googling "Binary Graph" returns definition of a "Binary Tree" which doesn't seem to fit the context here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary Graph is a graph data representation of a Binary Tree. Take the below Graph data (https://gremlify.com/scb244l635i) where each node can have left or right children.

```
g.addV('node').as('1').property(single, 'data', 22).
  addV('node').as('2').property(single, 'data', 16).
  addV('root').as('3').property(single, 'data', 9).
  addV('node').as('4').property(single, 'data', 5).
  addV('node').as('5').property(single, 'data', 2).
  addV('node').as('6').property(single, 'data', 11).
  addV('node').as('7').property(single, 'data', 15).
  addV('node').as('8').property(single, 'data', 10).
  addV('node').as('9').property(single, 'data', 1).
  addV('node').as('10').property(single, 'data', 8).
  addE('left').from('1').to('2').
  addE('left').from('3').to('4').
  addE('right').from('3').to('6').
  addE('left').from('4').to('5').
  addE('right').from('4').to('10').
  addE('left').from('5').to('9').
  addE('left').from('6').to('8').
  addE('right').from('6').to('7').
  addE('right').from('7').to('1')
```

[image]

Conditions:

1. Each node can have only one parent node.
2. Each node can have at most 2 children (left and right) nodes.

Comment: thanks for your answer and images to help clarify! So if I'm understanding correctly, a "binary graph" is the exact same thing as a "binary tree". Is this correct? In other words, a "binary graph" is comprised of nodes which can have AT MOST two pointers (left or right). Also, each node in the "graph" can only RECEIVE one pointer from one parent node.

Comment: @regs Exactly, beautifully explained. I am adding your observations as well in my answer for future reference for myself and others.